# Is memcached designed differently to better handle larger payloads? Is it multi-threading that makes it more ideal for larger values?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached

I know redis is great for storing key/value pairs like memcached.  Redis has a richer set of data types etc.

But since redis is single threaded, I believe it is not ideal for larger payloads.  Say for a CMS or web page caching (entire HTML that may be large, articles etc) memcached is more suited for this.

Is this because memcached is multi-threaded?  If you try this with redis it will block other calls and it maybe doesn't stream large payloads efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because memcached is multi-threaded.